# Iterating through an integer column to see if the value is contained in the range of a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists: one list contains integers, the second contains a list of ranges.

Here is what those lists would be defined as:

```
range_list = [range(0,7), range(7,12), range(12,22), etc.]
integer_list = [9, 3, 100, etc.]
```

Both lists are of the same size.

I want to label the integers in my integer_list according to which range it is in, in the range_list. There is a label_list already in place such that the nth range in range_list corresponds to the nth label in label_list. By this I mean that if my integer is in the first range (zeroth element of range_list), it would receive a label of label_list[0]. My problem is how to correctly iterate through the integer_list and range_list.

I took my own swing at the problem

```
empty_list = [] #list where the labels will be appended to
for i in integer_list:
  for j in range_list:
      if i in j:
         empty_list.append(label_list[j])
         break
      else:
        continue
```

with this approach it seems that I am going on an infinite loop (or severely time taxing at the very least).

If it helps to clarify what label_list is defined as, this is it:

```
label_list = ['Dementia', 'Schizophrenia', 'Diabetes I', etc..]
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have associations, you should probably be thinking about using a dictionary. I would just explode out the range so that you have a dictionary that goes from int to the label. And then create a dictionary that associates the int to the the looked up value.

```
range_list = [range(0,7), range(7,12), range(12,22)]
label_list = ['Dementia', 'Schizophrenia', 'Diabetes I']
integer_list = [9, 3, 10]

table = {}
for int_range, label in zip(range_list, label_list):
    for i in list(int_range):
        table[i] = label

{i: table[i] for i in integer_list}
```

Output

```
{9: 'Schizophrenia', 3: 'Dementia', 10: 'Schizophrenia'}
```

Note I've changed your example to use the int 10 instead of 100 because you don't define a range that includes 100.

Comment: What if integer_list has more elements than do range_list and label_list?